# jQuery for personalised images - Similar to gettingpersonal.co.uk/

Tags: jquery, image-manipulation, personalization

Is anybody aware of any scripts around that will function in the same way, or similar to this - http://www.gettingpersonal.co.uk/personalised-pictures/personalised-tree-carving-print.htm

Alternatively, does anybody know exactly how this is done on Getting Personal?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a server-side script, so it could really be anything. jQuery's not going to help you here; your best bet is going to be a canvas-based solution if you want to do it in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

To me that looks like the result of a personalisation system like [XMPie](http://www.xmpie.com/), specifically the [uImage](http://www.xmpie.com/uimage) component of that package via Photoshop.

It is very expensive software available from Xerox, you can make your own using image magick, but it is very difficult.